# October cms error: [SQL Server] There is already an object named 'user_groups' in the database

Tags: sql-server, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

New to October CMS. I setup the CMS on IIS with SQL Server, and have gotten this error several times. This time, while following a tutorial on how to create a plugin, the error appears again. The error seemingly has nothing to do with the creation of the plugin.

Please advise. Thanks so much!

[image: October CMS error]

Answer (score 1):

user_groups is a octobercms system table, it's already in use.
You cannot use that name for your own plugin.

Try to use the naming convention: `authorname_pluginname_model_name`

So in your case

```
trentlarson_myplugin_user_groups
```

as table name.

That way you also prevent collisions with other plugins that might use similarly named tables.

Most databases have a 64 character limit on table names.(not looking at oracle)

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me so quickly. I want to clarify that I understand that the user_groups table is part of the system and I did not add or use the user_group table for this plugin. I use the OctoberCMS Builder to create a plugin and this error happened after I clicked the "ok" button when creating the plugin.

Comment: hmm, seems like october:up was called via artisan, and somehow the user plugin had not registered it installed the tables.

Comment: I think the error is related to the IIS/MSSQL setup - mainly MSSQL. I installed a separate instance using IIS/SQLite and this error does not occur.

Comment: I used to have the sql server and  hack the sh*t out of october. For a year I ran on a hacked outdated version. I finally convinced my boss to switch to mariadb/mysql. Pro tip. don't use sql server. it needs too many hacks. I already submitted a lot of patches to october for it, but there are so many use cases one needs to patch out. like those user group permissions. October does some kind of query that's simply not possible under sql server the way it's built up by the query builder.
Switch to mariadb/mysql, postgres, don't use sql server unless you like to hack and not upgrade